# Unable to apply migrations to Heroku postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

The database is postgres and framework is django.
Running migrations works fine on localhost but not on Heroku server. I cannot drop or reset the database because it contains important data. I backed up the database, reset it and all migrations worked, but when I restored the backup, it reverted back to the old migration state and the problem persisted.
I don't know how to transfer only the data from the backup into a reset database instead of also transferring the old database structure.

When I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` I get this error:

```
No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app4', 'users' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Using `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations app-name` does not help either.

Is there a way to map and transfer just the user data from the old database into the new one? Or is there a way to brute force the old database to accept the new migration structure?
I would be glad if I get some help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of ***`heroku run python manage.py showmigrations`***?

Comment: @JPG  It shows the migrations I have on localhost

Comment: Have you made sure to commit your migration files and push those commits to Heroku?

Comment: @Chris, yes I did that

Comment: It looks like you have model changes that are not captured in a migration. I'm not sure how you got into that situation (and it can be tricky to resolve), but the short version is you need to `makemigrations` _locally_, then commit the new migration files, then deploy, then run migrations on Heroku.

Comment: @Chris, yes I made changes to the models and then  ````makemigrations ```` locally which worked perfectly. The issue is that it does not work on Heroku. Actually some migration history was deleted some time ago.

Comment: You need to _commit the new migration files_ and deploy them to Heroku. The committed models and migrations need to match up. Make sure to commit changes to them together.

Comment: @Chris I have done the commit over and over again before pushing to heroku but the same issue. Can I edit the django_migrations table?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend directly editing that table unless you _really_ know what you're doing. "Actually some migration history was deleted some time ago"—well that's a problem. Why did you delete migration files? You _need them_.

Comment: @Chris I deleted them when I had issues migrating on localhost. That worked but it has now affected the production database.

Comment: Deleting migration files is almost never the right course of action. Your migrations and your database schema are likely out of sync. We can't help you with this in comments' you'll need to ask another question about this specific issue and include your current migrations, the ones you deleted, and likely more. Deleting them might have seemed to "work" at the time, but it almost certainly broke things further.